When can "we" be used in a research paper?
I know the whole thing about not using first person pronouns because that makes it more personal and less objective, save for the research being an experiment conducted by the author(s). But could you use "we" in a general sense, such as "and even now, we celebrate Thanksgiving to commemorate when Pilgrims and Native Americans finally made peace."? I know technically saying "Americans" would be better, but would using "we" be acceptable there?

Academic writing styles have changed fundamentally over the past centuries. Up until and including the nineteenth century, it was the convention that single authors write in the pluralis auctoris, the author's plural, to refer to themselves or that references to the author were to be avoided, to give an impression of greater objectivity.
This is no longer the convention today.
In the natural sciences is has become the norm to clearly name who has done what to avoid ambiguity and confusion as well as to acknowledge the limits to any scientists objectivity. For example, these are the recommendations of the American Psychological Association in the current 7th edition of their Publication Manual (APA):

4.16 First- Versus Third-Person Pronouns
Pronouns replace nouns, and each pronoun should refer clearly to its antecedent. To avoid ambiguity in attribution, use the first person rather than the third person when describing the work you did as part of your research and when expressing your own views. If you are writing a paper by yourself, use the pronoun “I”; do not use the pronoun “we” to refer to yourself if you do not have coauthors (see also Section 4.17). If you are writing a paper with coauthors, use the pronoun “we.” Do not refer to yourself or your coauthors in the third person as “the author(s)” or “the researcher(s).”
However, use the third person to refer to the specific contribution of a particular coauthor within a paper with multiple authors. In the following example, Sonia J. Cousteau is one of the authors of the paper:

We assessed children’s language abilities. Sonia J. Cousteau, who is a speech-language pathologist, trained all testers.

Keep in mind that if you refer to coauthors by name in the text of your manuscript, you may need to mark out their names each time they appear if your paper is to undergo masked review (see Section 12.7).
4.17 Editorial “We”
Do not use “we” to refer to people in general, as in “We live on the same planet, but we rarely truly understand each other”; this use is called the editorial “we.” It is especially important to avoid the editorial “we” in multiauthored papers because readers may wonder whether you are referring to all people, members of your professional group(s), or yourself and your coauthors. Substitute a more specific noun or clarify your usage.
Correct: Psychological researchers typically study decision making in a laboratory setting.
Incorrect: We typically study decision making in a laboratory setting.

The ninth edition of Kate L. Turabian's A Manual for Writers of Research Papers, Theses, and Dissertations recommends:

11.1.7 Use First-Person Pronouns Appropriately
Almost everyone has heard the advice to avoid using I or we in academic writing. In fact, opinions differ on this point. Some teachers tell students never to use I, because it makes their writing “subjective.” Others encourage using I as a way to make writing more lively and personal.
Most instructors and editors do agree that two uses of I should be avoided:

Insecure writers begin too many sentences with I think or I believe (or their equivalent, In my opinion). Readers assume that you think and believe what you write, so you don’t have to say you do.
Inexperienced writers too often narrate their research: First I consulted . . . , then I examined . . . , and so on. Readers care less about the story of your research than about its results (see 6.1).

But we believe, and most editors of scholarly journals agree, that the first person is appropriate on two occasions. That last sentence illustrates one of them: we believe . . . that the first person . . .

An occasional introductory I (or we) believe can soften the dogmatic edge of a statement. Compare this blunter, less qualified version:

But we believe, and most editors of scholarly journals agree that the first person is appropriate on two occasions.

The trick is not to hedge so often that you sound uncertain or so rarely that you sound smug.

A first-person I or we is also appropriate when it’s the subject of a verb naming an action unique to you as the writer of your argument. Verbs referring to such actions typically appear in introductions (I will show/argue/prove/claim that X) and in conclusions (I have demonstrated/concluded that Y). Since only you can show, prove, or claim what’s in your argument, only you can say so with I:

In this report, I will show that social distinctions at this university are . . .

On the other hand, researchers rarely use the first person for an action that others must repeat to replicate their research. Those words include divide, measure, weigh, examine, and so on. Researchers rarely write sentences with active verbs like this:
15a. I calculated the coefficient of X.
Instead, they’re likely to write in the passive, because anyone can do that:
15b. The coefficient of X was calculated.


Those same principles apply to we, if you’re one of two or more authors. But many instructors and editors object to two other uses of we:

the royal we used to refer reflexively to the writer
the all-purpose we that refers to people in general

For example:

We must be careful to cite sources when we use data from them. When we read writers who fail to do that, we tend to distrust them.

In the end, though, those having authority decide. If your instructor or editor flatly forbids I or we, then so be it. When you have that authority, you can make a different choice.
Here is a final piece of advice. If you follow our seven principles, your readers will likely find your writing clear. But you can test your writing by having someone read it back to you. If that person stumbles over a passage, you can bet your readers will struggle with it too.

The last example (16) clearly advises against your use of what Turabian calls the "all-purpose we that refers to people in general". I'm not American and I don't "celebrate Thanksgiving to commemorate when Pilgrims and Native Americans finally made peace". Your we wrongly includes me in that tradition. In fact I'm sure not all Americans celebrate Thanksgiving, and not all that do do so to commemorate that peace. Avoiding that we forces you to become aware of false generalisations and be more exact (and scientific) in your writing. Who exactly celebrates Thanksgiving to commemorate that peace, and what are you trying to say with that?

Ah, I see, thank you for clarifying. Also I thought that was why people celebrate Thanksgiving, I dunno.

@idkausernamelol If you are happy with an answer and find it helpful, you can upvote it. If it answers your question, you can accept it as answer. — As for Thanksgiving, I was just pointing out to you that your essay might be read by people who are not American (and do not celebrate Thanksgiving) or who do celebrate Thanksgiving but for another reason (e.g. for the family dinner or for the presents – not every American is a devout Christian). I'm sure there are people who celebrate Thanksgiving for the reasons you specified, but not all of your readers.

I wasn't even writing an essay with that, it was just an example. I don't have 15 rep though.

In APA, "we" means "my coauthors and I" (usually). It should not be used as a vague, generic term, though they do give a "correct" example that uses it as part of a longer descriptive phrase: "As young adults, we often worry…". However, since using "we" even as part of a longer phrase would awkward for any non-American readers, I would replace it entirely, either with "Americans" or with the passive. See also The “no first-person” myth
Other styles (including more localized ones used alongside APA) may say different on the matter.
